# Help understanding the proof of Trace Theorem given in Evans

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, proof-explanation

I need help to understand the proof of the Trace Theorem given in  *Evans L.C. Partial differential equations (AMS, 1997)*:

> Asume $U$ is a bounded open set and that $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $T:W^{1,p}(U) \to L^p(\partial U)$ such that:
>
> $\quad$(i) $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$ if $u \in W^{1,p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$
>
> and
>
> $\quad$(ii) $\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \le C \| U \|_{W^{1,p} (U)},$ for each $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, with the constant $C$ depending only on $p$ and $U$.

The proof provided starts like this:

[image: Trace_theorem_proof_firstpart]

Okay, so we first asume that there is a neighborhood $U_{x^0}$ of $x^0$ such that $U_{x^0} \subset \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n=0\}$ and prove **(1)**.

Then the proof continues by saying "If $\partial U$ is not flat near $x^0$", we straighten out the boundary near $x^0$ to obtain the setting above. Applying estimate (1) and changing variables... (The proof continues)

Could someone clarify me a little more precisely what **straighten out the boundary near $x^0$** means?

**Updated:** This is the definition of open set of class $C^1 $ which gives us a diffeomorphism to the set $Q_0$ which is "flat".

> We define the following sets:
>
> - $R_+ = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n \geq 0\} $
>
>   - $ Q = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \ y \  |x_n|<1 \}$
>   - $ Q_+=R_+ \cap Q $
>   - $ Q_0=\{(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \}$
>
> An open set $\Omega$ is of class $C^1$ if for every $x \in \partial \Omega$ there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
>   a bijective map $H: Q \to U_x$ such that:
>
> - $H \in C^1(\overline{Q})$
> - $H^{-1} \in C^1(\overline{U_x})$
> - $H(Q_+)=U_x \cap Q$
> - $H(Q_0)= U_x \cap \partial \Omega$

Comment: Find a differentiable map that transforms a piece of $\partial U$ near $x^0$ into a piece of a plane. Then you change variables in the integrals.

Comment: @TrialAndError Could you please explain it a bit more? I suppose you mean transform a neighborhood of $x^0$ into a piece of a hyperplane (into a piece of a $n-1-$ dimensional surface), Right?  Why do you have the guarantee to have that difeomorphism, is it simply because $U$ is open, right?

Comment: Having the diffeomorphism is essentially assumed by asserting that $\partial U$ is a $C^1$ manifold.

Comment: @TrialAndError And shouldn't the Jacobian appear due to the change of variables? The book says "Applying estimate (1) and changing variables we obtain the bound: $\int_{\Gamma} |u|^p dS \leq C \int_{U} |u|^p + |Du|^p dx$, where $\Gamma$ is some open subset of $\partial U$ cointaining $x_0$."

Comment: The Jacobian will be bounded above and below in the local neighborhood that you obtain by move normally off the $C^1$ boundary.

Comment: @TrialAndError Could you expand a little bit more how to obtain a bound for the Laplacian? I have added the definition of $C^1$ open set that I have been given.

Comment: @TrialAndError I suppose the bound is due to the fact that $DH $ is continuous on $\overline{Q}$ and also $DH^1$ is continuous on $\overline{U_x}$, which are both compact, but how can I make this precise?

Comment: You make a change of variables in the integral for a piece of the boundary and part of the open region. The change of variables maps part of a half space to this region with the planar part mapped to the $C^1$ boundary. The Jacobian of the transform will be uniformly bounded away from $0$ on this region.

Comment: @TrialAndError Sorry,  What does **uniformly bounded away from 0** mean?

Comment: $0 < \delta \le J(x)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood.

Comment: @TrialAndError But I need to bound the Jacobian, I mean, I need to have something like $0 < J(x) \leq \delta$

Comment: Of course it's bounded above, but you need it bounded below as well.

Comment: @TrialAndError So the bounded above is due to the fact that partial derivatives of H and $H^{-1}$ are continuous on a compact set, but how do I show it is bounded bellow?

Comment: @D1X Excuse me. I have read Appendix A but still go nowhere about the notation $C(\bar{U})$. By Evans' definition, any $u\in C(\bar{U})$ won't be defined on $\partial U$, but in the introduction to the trace theorem, he seems to allow $u$ to have values on $\partial U$. Why's that? Thank you.